# What is the preferred method of using Google for sign-in?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-plus, google-oauth

Google has a habit of providing multiple means to achieve a goal. And of ditching services when they feel like it. If I would need to implement a "sign-in with Google" authentication feature today, which one should I pick? [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/) or 
[Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/)? Or to put it differently: which one will survive the longest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Google Sign-in. It's the second iteration of Google+ Sign-In so it's pretty similar but is simplier and faster to implement. [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference) has `gapi.auth2` and `gapi.signin2` while [Google+ Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference#javascript_api) has `gapi.auth` and `gapi.signin`.

That being said authentication products generally have a deprecation period of a couple years so Google+ sign-in would be around for a long time even if it was deprecated today.